# Getting null value on click button

Tags: java, selenium

i have no idea how to solve this as i getting the correct xpath for the button selection but still getting null . Kindly advise . Thanks you

HTML CODE:

```
  <class=tip_skip rel="0">
```

CODE :

```
private static WebElement element = null;
    public static WebElement Skip_Advertising(WebDriver driver){

            element = driver.findElement(By.className("tip_skip"));
            //driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@class='tip_skip']")).click();
            //Log.info("My Account link element found");
            System.out.println("element=" + driver); 
            return element;

        }


public static void Execute(WebDriver d) throws Exception{


        String sUserName = ParameterExcelReader.getCellData(1, 1);

        String sPassword = ParameterExcelReader.getCellData(1, 2);

        wd.get(Constant.URL);

        wd.manage().window().maximize();

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Home_Page.Skip_Advertising(d).click();
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid HTML tag. Please copy/paste it from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you used variable `d` for as Webdriver object:
    `Home_Page.Skip_Advertising(d).click();`

But, in rest of code, it seems you create variable `wd` as Webdriver object. So change your code as:

```
Home_Page.Skip_Advertising(wd).click();
```